# document.getElementById("").innerHTML=event.data; into a variable

Tags: javascript, php

```
<script>
var source = new EventSource("panic.php");
source.onmessage=function(event) {
    document.getElementById("panic_status").innerHTML=event.data;
};
</script>
```

how do i set the element panic status into are variable in another script
for example

```
var name = document.getElementById("panic_status").value;
```

Comment: `var name = document.getElementById("panic_status").innerHTML;` ...?

Comment: if i use <h1>panic_status <div id="panic_status"></div></h1> if will show up the value coming from the panic_status bur i need to set up this in another script as variable so that i can manipulated the value

Comment: First of all, that's invalid HTML, you can not next a div into h1. Secondly ... still rather unclear what you want, resp. what your problem actually is. Please go read [ask].

Comment: Or this might in fact be just another duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 0):

so you could store in on the global `window` or `document` but global variables are bad and you should feel bad if you use them. :(
different idea though is to have a helper script that when you call just returns that value.

```
`var panic_status = function(){
  return document.getElementById("panic_status").innerHTML;
}`
```

this way you can grab that variable from other scripts easily and reliably. (as long as the script is declared above the other ones. Then you only need to do

```
var myVar = panicStatus();
```

but maybe im misunderstanding your question?